# Is openplug a mature development platform?

Tags: apache-flex, mobile, openplug

I'm looking into cross mobile device development and bumped into [openplug](http://www.open-plug.com/) (recently acquired by [Alcatel-Lucent](http://www.openplug.com/))
I've built an iPod touch app to in 10 min using this video
and the [training](http://developer.openplug.com/resources/training-material) page seems promising.

However, at the time of the question publish, the all mighty stackoverflow contains only 3 questions (4, after hitting post...). Generally speaking, googling it does not imply many success stories.

More ever, trying to port my spark-based app to openplug yield the insight that its using a flavor of flex SDK, which is incompatible with Adobe's.

Can anyone share of his experience or point to a decent app written with the product (other then [openplug themselves](http://www.open-plug.com/learn-more/showcase)...)?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer myself and for those out there thinking the same -

[No, it isn't...](http://developer.openplug.com/learn-more//363-cr15-important-notice)

Note: i did develop a iPod demo app in a ~week.
It felt like taking it to a product level would be very hard (annoying little bugs).

HTH